# ERROR in handling Multiple AJAX request on a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        var k = document.getElementById("usernamesignup").value;
        var urls = "AJAX.jsp?ver=" + k;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                //document.getElementById("err").style.color="red";
                document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", urls, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function loadXMLDoc1() {
        var xmlhttp;
        var k1 = document.getElementById("emailsignup").value;
        var urls1 = "AJAX1.jsp?ver1=" + k1;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                //document.getElementById("err1").style.color="red";
                document.getElementById("err1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", urls1, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

here is AJAX.jsp--[AJAX.jsp](http://jsfiddle.net/NZhXn/)

and here is AJAX1.jsp--[AJAX1.jsp](http://jsfiddle.net/rNP85/)

The first function - `loadXMLDoc()` checks from the Database about username availability using `AJAX.jsp` and returns the message string accordingly.

The second function - `loadXMLDoc1()` intends to do the same thing with the email, but doesn't return any messages as it does while checking the `USERNAME`.

Is there a problem with the code??? Whats the solution....
Thanks

Comment: Does the ajax makes request to same servlet/jsp ? Do you get any error in console? Did you see if it is hitting the target using some http watch utility ?

Comment: no, the request is handled by different JSP pages.. AJAX.jsp for the first function and AJAX1.jsp for the other....

Comment: Are you able to hit the JSP? Do you get any 404 in the browser console?Any AJAX fail error pop up in browser?

Comment: no there is no error shown in the console too....wait i am editing my question to attach the code of the two JSP pages...!!

Comment: question has been edited..

Answer (score 0):

THANKS GUYS FOR YOUR VIEWS AND RESPONSES, but this is where i was missing out...i was declaring the same XMLHttpRequest variable for the two requests...

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
```

Instead what i had done is declaring a new variable for the second function XMLDoc1()--

```
var xmlhttp1;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

and change the variable name accordingly wherever applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Charles to debug the request and the response